# Using htaccess to configure Apache and Passenger for Ruby

Tags: ruby, apache, .htaccess, rubygems, passenger

I've been trying to install a ruby app called Openproject on my bluehost account. I followed the Openproject guide.

https://www.openproject.org/open-source/manual-installation/manual-installation-guide/

I updated ruby and node using rbenv and nodenv. I was able to follow up to the section "Finish the Installation of OpenProject," and I didn't get any error up to this point.

However, I wasn't sure how to tackle the section "Servce OpenProject with Apache and Passenger." The guide asks to configure apache to load the right passenger, but Bluehost doesn't provide access to httpd.conf. Then I found the guide for Ruby from Bluehost indicating that I can use .htaccess to configure.

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails

I copied the .htaccess from the guide and put it in openproject/public folder.
However, if I open mydomain.com/openproject, it displays the list of files inside openproject folder. If I open mydomain.com/openproject/public, I get the error below. I also tried to move .htaccess to openproject folder instead of openproject/public, but I get the same result.
I noticed a couple of things from the error message, but I'm not sure how to fix them.
1. The error indicates "No such file or directory - config.ru," even though openproject folder has the file config.ru.
2. The error indicates that Application root is /home5/account/public_html. Shouldn't it be /home5/account/public_html/openproject?
Anyways, here's the entire error message.

Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

These are the possible causes:
There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.

A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:

> No such file or directory - config.ru   Exception class:
>   Errno::ENOENT   Application root:   /home5/account/public_html
>   Backtrace: # File Line Location   0
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 675 in
>   `lstat'   1
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 675 in`
>   lower_privilege'   2
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 198 in
>   `prepare_app_process'   3
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   156 in`block in initialize_server'   4
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in
>   `report_app_init_status'   5
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   154 in`initialize_server'   6
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   204 in `start_synchronously'   7
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   180 in`start'   8
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb
>   129 in `start'   9
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   253 in`block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'   10
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb
>   132 in `lookup_or_add'   11
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   246 in`block in spawn_rack_application'   12
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb
>   82 in `block in synchronize'   13 prelude> 10:in`synchronize'   14
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb
>   79 in `synchronize'   15
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   244 in`spawn_rack_application'   16
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   137 in `spawn_application'   17
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
>   275 in`handle_spawn_application'   18
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   357 in `server_main_loop'   19
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb
>   206 in`start_synchronously'   20
>   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99
>   in ` '

Powered by Phusion Passenger, mod_rails / mod_rack for Apache and Nginx.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Readability is essential in a question. Please read [the documentation for formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your text. The harder it is for us to decipher your question, the longer it takes to help you. Also, for good or bad, some people decide whether to help based on the work you put into asking your question. You're asking them to take time to help you, so take time to help them. Also, remove the secondary, diluting question, "On a related note, where does rbenv set..." It's not related to the primary question.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting reference! Hopefully it's better now. I also removed the secondary question.